# Passing data to SCSS/SASS and update DOM

Tags: sass

So Sass has some really nice functions to create complex logic inside your css. It would be great if you could actually pass on data from a front-end framework like React or Svelte, and pass it on to your SCSS and have it update. A conceptual example:

page.tsx

```
onClick={setColor(element.Color = 'blue')}
```

style.scss

```
element {
   color: $element.Color: 
}
```

I'm pretty sure it's not possible at the current stage, since SCSS is just compiled into CSS. But does anyone know of any new innovations or framework exploring this? Or some pattern that comes close to this experience (excluding CSS-in-JS frameworks)?

Comment: If you didn't hear about it, it might help https://styled-components.com.

Comment: You can do that today with [css-custom-variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties), no need to change how sass works.

Comment: @yousoumar, that's a CSS-in-JS framework, and you cannot use it with Sass.

Comment: @Martin, unrelated to my question. Also those are css variables, not sass.

Comment: @SaroVerhees You wrote `Or some pattern that comes close to this experience` and I pointed you to css vars, which can exactly do what you are trying to do. And yes you can use css vars in SCSS. And you can update css vars programmatically from within your js.

Comment: @Martin, you can't pass on CSS variable values to Sass values. At least, you can store the CSS variable name in there, but you cannot do any sass functions with it, as it will not actually hold the value but just the name. Also not sure how it relates to my question that this could be a similar pattern. Can you provide an example? Maybe you have some interesting insights on passing on data, even if you cant use sass functions on them.

Answer (score 1):

CSS variables can be changed during runtime, unlike their SCSS counterparts. But you can use both in SCSS. The former will only hold any meaningful value during runtime and can't be used as input to any SASS functions.
If you need any logic to be performed on those values that goes beyond what `calc()` can do you will have to use a javascript function during runtime.

Here is an example that shows how a user-provided value during runtime can be propagated into the CSS to influence the style rules:

```js
const input = document.getElementById('input');
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const onChange = (e) => {
  container.style.setProperty('--items-per-line', e.target.value);
};
input.addEventListener('input', onChange);
```

```css
.container {
  --items-per-line: 4;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
  padding-right: calc(100% - (var(--items-per-line) * (20px + 10px)));
}

.item {
  background: #ddd;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<label>
desired items per line
<input id="input" />
</label>
```

A combination of SCSS and CSS vars can be used thus:

```scss
    $items-per-line: 4;
    $item-size: 20px;
    $gap-size: 10px;

    .container {
      --items-per-line: #{$items-per-line};
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      gap: $gap-size;
      padding-right: calc(100% - (var(--items-per-line) * #{$item-size + $gap-size}));
    }

    .item {
      background: #ddd;
      height: $item-size;
      width: $item-size;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Martin for the great example. This technique indeed does allow for doing amazing CSS and JS runtime rendering. I like your example a lot. 

With my original question I was really trying to explore if there were any options to have it pass on to SASS. Because Sass has amazing functions, logic and datatypes like objects and arrays. But it all seems so useless if you can't really have a nice way to update it with JS (keeping the relations)

Answer (score 0):

I would make a scss function or class like "text-blue" and use that in the JS. JS is not meant to control styles, that's what css is for.

Comment: That's why it would be really nice to keep all CSS in the CSS files, separated from the JS. But sometimes you need dynamic styling, so it would be great if you could use the data from JS directly in your SASS, instead of setting CSS with JS. 

Setting a color to blue isn't the best example as a use case, but imagine you have a `content:$value` property that needs to be retrieved from a database?